# C++ Combine enum and string into a map-like variable, able to be used with both int and string

Tags: c++, string, enums

Suppose I have an `enum`:

```
enum Types
{
    TYPE_ASCENDING,
    TYPE_DESCENDING
};
```

and I use it to it... anywhere in the code. Say `if(bla < TYPE_ASCENDING)`, or with a `switch/case`. The real `enum` is much larger.

Whatever the results of the checks (or anything else), it needs to be `std::cout` in a prettier way to let the user know what happened. So, continuing the `if()` example, it might be something like this:

```
if(bla < TYPE_ASCENDING)
    std::cout << "Ascending.\n";
```

All these happen inside a class. My question: is there a way to define some type of variable/STL/anything that would allow storing both `enum`-like and `std::string`-like variables, but would also let me use, separately, both types?

One thought was a `namespace`, but it seems it can't be used inside a class. To exemplify, here's what it would have looked like:

```
namespace Type
{
    enum Types
    {
        ASCENDING,
        DESCENDING
    };
    std::string s[2] {"Ascending", "Descending"};
};
```

and it would have been called as `Type::ASCENDING` for the `if()`, and `Type::s[0]` for the string. But, no `namespace` inside a class, so it's not a solution.

Using `std::map` only lets me use `int` as the index, so I can only use this:

```
std::map<Types, std::string> m {{TYPE_ASCENDING, "Ascending}, {TYPE_DESCENDING, "Descending"}};
```

as `m[0]`, or `m[TYPE_ASCENDING]`, but I can't call it for it's index to be used inside the `if()`. For that I have to call the `enum`, separately, which means I have both an `enum` and a `map`, two variables. I need one, unified, to avoid chasing variable names all over the code.

If I use a `struct`, I can't access directly `Struct::TYPE_DESENDING`, I need to create an object.

I can use an `enum` and a `std::string` array/vector, but that means that, again, I have to call two variables, separately, and I'd like them to be unified.

Is what I want possible?

Comment: Have you tried `map<Type, string>`?

Comment: @SauravSahu As I mentioned, I tried, but that won't let me use the `int` part. If I have `std::map<Type, std::string> x`, then how do I call the `Type` part? Say, if I have `if(bla > TYPE_ASCENDING)`, how do I make that with a `map`?

Comment: Okay, I thought I had an answer for you. Then I re-read what you wrote, and I have no idea what your issue is. So please clear up you post.

Comment: @StoryTeller I just read your post and was about to post a comment. I'll rewrite, hopefully more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have that mechanism in native C++. You can write a map / mapper function.

```
enum class E
{
    ONE,
    TWO
};

std::unordered_map<E,std::string> eStrings { {E::ONE,"ONE"},{E::TWO,"two"}};
```

*While this is C++11 you can do the same for older C++ versions*

Then you can use this like

```
std::cout << eStrings[E::ONE];
```

The issue here is you have to maintain this manually. So when you add a new value to the enum you have to manually add a new entry to the map.

The same would be true for writing a class or functions to have this behavior. You always have to duplicate the code of enum declaration and the mapping to the string.

A solution here would be to use some tool to generate these.

You can define in some file your enum (this is just some random format and only intended for explaining this. Chose whatever you want in your own defenition file)

```
E
- ONE
- TWO
```

And then generate the C++ enum and Map in a header and/or cpp file.

```
enum class <name>
{
    <foreach:> <value>,
};

std::unordered_map< <name> ,std::string> eStrings 
{ 
    <foreach:> {<name>::<value>,"<value>"},
};
```

If you don't like having a map this approach is pretty flexible. You can also generate a switch case statement if you like

```
std::string getString(<name> e)
{
    switch(e)
    {
        <foreach:> case <name>::<value>: return "<value>";
    }
}
```

The syntax here is no standard for anything just some "pseudocode" to visualize the concept. There are several ways to generate c++ code out there. You can choose whatever you want or write your own program for this.

**Note:**

This is also just a general concept. You can wrap this functioniality / map etc into another class, make it static etc. for optimizations and not put it in global scope.

---

If you need something more fancy than just a map to lookup the string you can create a class with this concept or another map which does just the reverse lookup. It's more about the fact that you most likely have to generate the code by an external tool.

Comment: While you were posting your comment, I modified my question. I hope it's more legible. I hope it changes your answwer for the better. :-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I don't think this can be done in c++ (or if so not easily). When your concerns are the variable names you pollute your program with put them in an own namespace. If you don't like having the map you can hide it inside a function or autogenerate a switch-case which returns the strings instead of a map. But you will not get around autogeneration I fear. I have added the switch case as an example though. But due to the lack of reflection (what java has) you will not get this functionality out of the box

Comment: I was afraid of this. I might try your suggestion, an external `namespace`, after all, it's only an `enum` and its representative strings, should this be a concern if the class is to be sealed in rest? I mean, there are also `enum`s that have names, for example for polynomials, "Chebyshev", "Pascal", etc, which would, eventually, be used to call the functions in the class. I don't think it's such a blatant disregard for "privacy", in terms of a class, except that, maybe, the namespace can be changed from outside? Can this be a concern for malicious intent?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I don't know exactly what you mean in case of malicious intent. But you can also generate this inside a class and not a namespace. Where you generate the code (extra class or namespace) does not matter as long as it produces valid c++. So you can also put this in a class or a member function of the class. And have the map be a local static of one function. This is pretty flexible on where you put what and how.

Comment: Maybe malicious was too harsh, I meant any unauthorized access from outside. At any rate, a `namespace` will allow me to call its variables without creating an object, while a class won't. But maybe I can get around that. For a `namespace`, I call `Namespace::stuff`, so maybe I can make an external class `Types`, create a member variable `Types *types`, then simply call `types->stuff`. Now that I spelled it, I think this will be the way. Thank you for all the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Reading **Hayts** answer I see that what I originally wrote may be relevant for the auto generation of code aspect. So I leave it here.

---

Seeing as regular old `enum`s are implicitly convertible to `int` (as opposed to `enum classes`), you can simply use a `map<int, string>`.

Now, to the interesting part, generating it semi-automatically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Thing {

    enum Type {
#     define ENUM_DEF(v, s) v,
        ENUM_DEF(TYPE_ASCENDING,  "Ascending")
        ENUM_DEF(TYPE_DESCENDING, "Descending")
#     undef ENUM_DEF
    };

    std::map<int, std::string> string;

    Thing() {
#     define ENUM_DEF(v, s) string[v] = s;
        ENUM_DEF(TYPE_ASCENDING,  "Ascending")
        ENUM_DEF(TYPE_DESCENDING, "Descending")
#     undef ENUM_DEF
    }
};


int main() {
    Thing t;
    std::cout << t.string[0];
    return 0;
}
```

I used a technique known as [X-Macros](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387). The premise is that you pass all the argument needed for your enum into the macro. Then you *define* the macro, depending on how you need the arguments to be used. So firstly:

```
#   define ENUM_DEF(v, s) v,
```

This just expands the enum token as you'd provide it to a regular enum defintion.

Then, in `Thing`s c'tor:

```
#     define ENUM_DEF(v, s) string[v] = s;
```

It expands to the statement you need to populate the map.

And to address one last point you may have issue with: Do you really have to do all this repetition, retyping `ENUM_DEF` all the time?
Well, luckily you don't. You can move those statements into their own file, let's call it `type_enum.def`:

```
#ifdef ENUM_DEF
  ENUM_DEF(TYPE_ASCENDING,  "Ascending")
  ENUM_DEF(TYPE_DESCENDING, "Descending")
#endif //ENUM_DEF
```

And the original code becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Thing {

    enum Type {
#   define ENUM_DEF(v, s) v,
#     include "type_enum.def"
#   undef ENUM_DEF
    };

    std::map<int, std::string> string;

    Thing() {
#     define ENUM_DEF(v, s) string[v] = s;
#       include "type_enum.def"
#     undef ENUM_DEF
    }
};


int main() {
    Thing t;
    std::cout << t.string[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Currently I am using an external, private class (a simple header file), accessible only by the class using it, inside with a simple `enum` and a `std::string[]`. If the code will tend to grow later on, your answer could come in handy. Thank you for the answer. It's strange that I saw no alert when I logged in, is it because you deleted the answer before?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, yes. It's my original answer from before you clarified your post. I wasn't sure it's relevant. But your conversation & acceptance of **Hayt**'s answer made me think you can still make use of the X-Macros reference.